# get bool from IAwaitable<IMessageActivity>

Tags: c#, botframework

Confirmation Prompt with ParseMessage sending text over to Luis, and then I return true or false. I've set debugger in this file and verified response returns bool.

Code in question. When I get result back it says `Cannot implicitly convert IAwaitable<bool> to bool`, which is where `Convert.ToBoolean()` came in; still no luck however.

How can I check the returned bool so that I can verify results in this if statement.

In this current code sample it just sends back a message in bot emulator saying:

Exception: Unable to cast object of type ‘Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait`2[Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask,System.Boolean]’ to type ‘System.IConvertible’.

Edit: Updated for more code

RootDialog.cs

```
    private async Task SendWelcomeMessageAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        await context.PostAsync("Hi, I'm the Basic Multi Dialog bot. Let's get started.");

        context.Call(new ConfirmLuisPrompt(), this.ConfirmLuisPromptAfter);
    }

    private async Task ConfirmLuisPromptAfter(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<bool> result)
    {
        //var res = Convert.ToBoolean(result);
        var confirm = await result;

        if (confirm) 
        {
            //yes
            context.Call(FormDialog.FromForm(PersonInfo.BuildForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart), this.PersonInfoAfter);
        }else
        {
            //no
            await context.PostAsync($"Ok, let's get you started");

            context.Call(FormDialog.FromForm(PatientInfo.BuildForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart), InHospital);

        }
    }
```

ConfirmLuisPrompt.cs

```
 [Serializable]
public class ConfirmLuisPrompt : IDialog<bool>
{
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        await context.PostAsync("Do you have insurance?");

        context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
    }

    private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {

        dynamic m = await result;
        var message = m.Text.ToString();
        //context.Wait( ParseMessage(context, message));
        bool response = await ParseMessage(message);
        context.Done(response);
        //context.PostAsync(response.toString());
    }


    public bool ParseMessage(string input)
    {
        LuisClient luisClient = new LuisClient("<key1>", "<key2>");
        Task<LuisResult> resultTask = luisClient.Predict(input);
        resultTask.Wait();
        LuisResult result = resultTask.Result;

        if (result.TopScoringIntent.Name == "Yes")
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (result.TopScoringIntent.Name == "No")
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not convert just do: `result.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` which should return a boolean

Answer (score 3):

You just need to do the following in your `ConfirmLuisPromptAfter` method:

```
var confirm = await result;

if (confirm) 
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: says `Exception: ‘bool’ does not contain a definition for ‘GetAwaiter’`  which seems odd since it's an IAwaitable lol

Comment: I think this comment is for the other answer.

Comment: Then there is something else wrong in your code. Please update your question with all the code of your dialog.